# Connecting java swing classes

Tags: java, swing

I am creating an Invoice System to fit a unique invoice machine and using Javafx with Swing. I am only at the beginning of my project, and have created a signup page that is attached to an SQLite database. currently, i am trying to connect my signup page (Invoice1.java) to the Home page (home.java)
Currently I have a button on the signup page that when clicked, a popup window saying that the account is created and the 'OK' button on the popup is supposed to bring you to the Home page. I have the button able to make the signup page invisable, however now instead of bringing up the home page, it brings up a blank window.
Would anyone know how to connect my two windows. I am trying to not use JForms, as for my project, it counts as low code, so would like to code it by hand.

this is my Invoice 1 class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package invoice1;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
/**
 *
 * @author kate3
 */

public class Invoice1 extends Home {
    private static JLabel nameLabel;
    private static JTextField nameText;
    private static JLabel passwordLabel;
    private static JTextField passwordText;
    private static JButton button;
   
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
            /*Creating  the signup form, part of code used from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iE8tZ0hn2Ws) 
            */ 
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setSize(350, 200);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(panel);
                                
                panel.setLayout(null);
                
                nameLabel = new JLabel("Business Name");
                nameLabel.setBounds(10, 20, 80, 25);
                panel.add(nameLabel);
                
                nameText = new JTextField(40);
                nameText.setBounds(100, 20, 165, 25);
                panel.add(nameText);
                
                passwordLabel = new JLabel ("Create Password");
                passwordLabel.setBounds (10, 50, 80, 25);
                panel.add(passwordLabel);
                
                passwordText = new JTextField(20);
                passwordText.setBounds(100, 50, 165, 25);
                panel.add(passwordText);
               
                button = new JButton("Create Account");
                button.setBounds(130, 110, 80, 25);
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        String name = nameText.getText();
                        String password = passwordText.getText();
                        addToDB(name, password);
                        
                        
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Account Created!");
                        panel.setVisible(false);
                        Home.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });
                panel.add(button);
                frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    /* keeping in file in case needed in future
    
    public void buttonPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String name = nameText.getText();
        String password = passwordText.getText();
        
        if(name.equals("kate") && password.equals("password")){
            successful.setText("Login successful!");
        }
      
    }*/
    
    //adding data inputted to database
    public static void addToDB ( String un, String pass){
            Connection dbCon = null;
        
        String strUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:testDB.db";
        try{
            dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(strUrl, "root", "root");
            System.out.println("Connected");
            
              Statement st = dbCon.createStatement();
              
              PreparedStatement stmt = dbCon.prepareStatement("Select * From loginDetails");
                st.executeUpdate("insert into loginDetails (username, password)"
                    + " values ('" + un + "' , '" + pass + "')");
                
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
            }
            
            
        }catch(SQLException e){
        
    }

}
  /*
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
*/
 }
```

This then is my home.java class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package invoice1;

import java.awt.PopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author kate3
 */
public class Home {
    private static JLabel homeLabel ;
    private static JButton invoiceButton;
    private static JButton invoiceHistory;
    private static JButton statementButton;
    private static JButton statementHistory;
    private static JButton productButton;
    private static JButton customerButton;
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel home = new JPanel();
        
        //linking Invoice1 JFrame
        Home.getInvoice1();
        
       // frame.setSize(350, 200);
        Home.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        home.setLayout(null);
        
        homeLabel = new JLabel("HOME");
        homeLabel.setBounds(100, 20, 80, 25);
        home.add(homeLabel);
        
        invoiceButton = new JButton("Create Invoice");
        invoiceButton.setBounds(100, 50, 80, 25);
        home.add(invoiceButton);
        
        statementButton = new JButton("Create Statement");
        statementButton.setBounds(100, 80, 80, 25);
        home.add(statementButton);
        
        invoiceHistory = new JButton("Invoice History");
        invoiceHistory.setBounds(100, 80, 80, 25);
        home.add(invoiceHistory);
        
        statementHistory = new JButton("Statement History");
        statementHistory.setBounds(100, 140, 80, 25);
        home.add(statementHistory);
        
        productButton = new JButton("Products");
        productButton.setBounds(100, 170, 80, 25);
        home.add(productButton);
        
        customerButton = new JButton("Customers");
        customerButton.setBounds(100, 200, 80, 25);
        home.add(customerButton);
        
        Home.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void setDefaultCloseOperation(int EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    static class Invoice1 extends Home {

        PopupMenu Invoice1;

        public Invoice1() {
        }
    }

    static void setVisible(boolean b) {
    }

    
    private static void getInvoice1() {
    }
    
}
```

Comment: what has "coding by hand" (whatever that is) to do with using JFrames or not? If you want those two classes to communicate with each other, they'll need to have access to each others instances

Comment: Also this is unrelated to JavaFX since you're using Swing.

Comment: @Stultuske they wrote "_JForms_", not "JFrames".

Comment: I suggest you look into a UI design pattern like [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter). It solves your concrete problem as well as many others you will find in your way.

Comment: @maloomeister thanks for the correction, I misread the comment :)

Comment: I'm not sure what `Home.setVisible(true);` in your `ActionListener` implementation is supposed to do. What you are probably looking for is [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). This allows you to switch `JPanel`s, according to what has to be shown on screen without the need of multiple `JFrame`s (which is considered bad practice). Working through the java swing basics with the [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) is also probably a good idea.

Comment: [mcve] please .. mind the __M__! And (though most probably unrelated  :) - __don't__ use static scope for anything, __don't__ disable automatic layouts (by null the manager)

Comment: By the way, if you are able to use JavaFX, then no need for Swing. JavaFX is the successor to Swing, and is under active development. Swing is now in maintenance-mode.